# Using Spring Expression Language to compile a Pattern object

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

Is it possible to use SpEL to compile a Pattern object using a regex expression from a properties file? I'm trying to avoid having the regex compiled each time a method within this class is called. I could use @Value to just set the regex to a String, then have a Pattern object with a getter and have the getter do a null check and only compile the Patter in that case. But it seems there should be a more concise way to accomplish this.

I'm hoping to replace this:

```
    @Value("${some.regex}")
    private String regex;

    private Pattern PATTERN = null;

    public Pattern getPattern() {
        if (PATTERN == null)
            PATTERN = Pattern.compile(regex);
        return PATTERN;
    }
```

With something along the lines of this:

```
    @Value("#{Pattern.compile('${some.regex}')}")
    private Pattern pattern;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend engineering your `@Value` to *provide* the regex pattern, then in an initialization method somewhere, validate that the regex is correct.

This gives you some obvious benefits:

- You have clarity into what is being done and how (SpEL can be a *wee* bit arcane)
- You have the ability to reliably and easily test it
- You can debug it while you develop it

My approach to this would be this.

```
@Component
public class FooClass {
    @Value("${some.regex}")
    private String regex;

    private Pattern pattern;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    }
    // rest of code here
}
```

Comment: Please, see my answer.

Comment: @ArtemBilan:  Yes, you've solved the technical problem; however, this doesn't mean that using the `T` pattern is usually a *good* idea.  Your answer is right but it has the opportunity to burn those who are less experienced or less versed with SpEL.  Worse, there's no opportunity to expand upon the expression.  IMO it *almost* feels like an abuse of the mechanism which should be leveraged for simpler transformations of text rather than wholesale Java objects, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: Well, what you say goes out of scope of the original request and it is really a matter of the opinion to use such a feature from SpEL or not. For example I'm not familiar with Kotlin and don't find it is a useful tool for Java developers, especially Open Source, but that's maybe is just my ignorance since the whole Internet is filled with Kotlin trends.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
    @Value("#{T(java.util.regex.Pattern).compile('${some.regex}')}")
```

The point is to use a `T` operator to get access to the `static` method. See more in the Reference Manual: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions-types

Answer (score 2):

While Artem's answer shows exactly what you asked for, this is a case where foregoing field injection ([which has quite a few problems](https://www.vojtechruzicka.com/field-dependency-injection-considered-harmful/)) can also provide a clean solution:

```
private Pattern pattern;

@Value("${some.regex}")
public void setRegex(String regex) {
    this.pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way i did this is creating my own Validation Annotation.

```
@Documented
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({METHOD,FIELD})
@Constraint(validatedBy=PropertyPatternValidator.class)
public @interface PropertyPattern {
    String property();
    String message() default "{validator.propertypattern}";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

And the Validator implementation

```
public class PropertyPatternValidator implements ConstraintValidator<PropertyPattern, CharSequence> {

private Map<String, Pattern> patterns = new HashMap<>();
private Pattern pattern;

@Override
public void initialize(PropertyPattern propPattern) {
    String property = propPattern.property();
    pattern = patterns.computeIfAbsent(property, prop -> {
        Properties applicationProps = (Properties) ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext()
                .getBean("applicationProps");
        String p = applicationProps.getProperty(prop);
        return Pattern.compile(p);
    });
}

@Override
public boolean isValid(CharSequence inputToValidate, ConstraintValidatorContext ctx) {
    CharSequence input = inputToValidate != null ? inputToValidate : "";
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(input);
    return m.matches();
}
}
```

Usage:

```
@PropertyPattern(property ="pattern.account")
private String accountNumber;
```

Then as long as `pattern.account` is in a properties file and set to a valid regex this will work.

Comment: i guess technically this doesn't use spel to solve the problem but does solve the problem of validating strings based on a value in a prop file.